# Returning form view in Symfony2 using Ajax/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Currently posting data from a drop-down menu. I am trying to basically the form that is returning and then insert it into the page.

## Select Drop-Down

```
<form method="POST" style="display: inline;">
    <select name="event_added" class="selectpicker">
        {% for subscription in form.peerEventSubscriptions %}
            <option value='{{typeDefEvent[loop.index0]}}'>{{ form_label(subscription.eventTypeHumanized) }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id = "addEventButton" data-rel="tooltip" title="AddEvent" value="Add Event" style="line-height: 1.5" />
</form>
```

## Ajax/Jquery

```
var addEvent = $("#addEventButton");

addEvent.click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('_add_new_sub_event') }}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { postVars: "EVENT_CLASS_JITTER EVENT_JITTER" }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            window.stop();
        });

});
```

## Controller

return this data, the form is valid.

```
return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
);
```

Getting a 500 internal server error. I just want to basically take this form and then render it to the current page, no refreshes.

Comment: What happens when you go directly to the url generated by `{{ path('_add_new_sub_event') }}` from your browser? (I bet it's also a 500 error)

Comment: Fair enough, but the information you provided isn't enough for anyone to help you here. A 500 error means that Symfony threw en exception somewhere that wasn't caught based on the url you provided. To debug it, you need to get more information on the exception that was thrown.

Comment: OK, so now we are getting a 400 bad request error.

Comment: Use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to simulate requests (including `POST`, or any HTTP, method type).

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to use FOSJsRoutingBundle,

Look at my example of my jQuery Ajax call:

```html
$('#addNewVariant').on('click', function(event){
                var hidden_input = $('#hidden_input').val();
                hidden_input++;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: Routing.generate('admin_products_addNewVariant', {'number' : hidden_input }),
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.loadingGif').show();
                        $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    success: function( returnedData ) {
                        $('#hidden_input').attr( 'value', hidden_input );
                        $('#ajaxVariantAdded').append('<li class="dd-item" data-id="'+returnedData.id+'"><div class="dd-handle"><a data-id="'+returnedData.id+'"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i> {{"tab.variant"|trans}} '+returnedData.name+'</a><a data-id="'+returnedData.id+'" data-toggle="modal" class="pull-right" href="#modal'+returnedData.id+'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></a></div></li>');
                        $( '.ajax' ).append( returnedData.form );
                        $('.variant').hide();
                        $('.variantItem'+returnedData.id).show();
                        $('.loadingGif').hide();
                        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function( returnedData){
                        $('.loadingGif').hide();
                        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is my route:

```html
admin_products_addNewVariant:
    pattern:  /addVariation/{number}
    defaults: { _controller: "ProductsBundle:BackEnd/Products:addNewVariant" }
    options:
        expose: true
```

Finally this is my function:

```html
public function addNewVariantAction($number){
        $entity = new Variant();
        $form = $this->createForm(new VariantType($number), $entity)->createView();
        $response = new JsonResponse(array(
                'form' => $this->renderView('ProductsBundle:Administration:Products/NewFormVariant/new.html.twig',array(
                        'form'          => $form,
                        'number'        => $number,
                    )
                ),
                'name'      => $number+1,
                'id'        => $number,
            ));

        return $response;
    }
```

I hope that my answer give a help.